# R - How to put aggregated row results as columns

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

Suppose there is dataframe df

```
age category
12  A
15  B
12  A
13  C
14  B
14  D
```

I want to use aggregate to find the number of occurrences in each category {A, B, C, D} for each age. The number of A, B, C and D respectively are established as columns so the output data frame should look like

```
age A B C D
12  2 0 0 0
13  0 0 1 0
14  0 1 0 1
15  0 1 0 0
```

**Attempt**

```
agdf <- aggregate(df, by=list(df$age, df$category), FUN=length)
```

But doing this only gives me

```
age category x
12  A        2
15  B        1
14  B        1
13  C        1
14  D        1
```

Another problem is that the original `df` has other columns but they have been omitted for simplicity. Yet with this aggregate approach using `FUN=length`, it turns all those other columns into the same count value as `x`. How can I keep those values?

E.g.

```
age category x  y  z
12  A        2  2  2
15  B        1  1  1
14  B        1  1  1
13  C        1  1  1
14  D        1  1  1
```

but I want y and z to keep their original values, only need 1 count column x

How to massage it to the desired structure?

Comment: `table(df)` or even `xtabs(~., df1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xtabs(~., df1)

    category
age  A B C D
  12 2 0 0 0
  13 0 0 1 0
  14 0 1 0 1
  15 0 1 0 0

table(df1)
    category
age  A B C D
  12 2 0 0 0
  13 0 0 1 0
  14 0 1 0 1
  15 0 1 0 0

reshape2::dcast(df1, age~category)
  age A B C D
1  12 2 0 0 0
2  13 0 0 1 0
3  14 0 1 0 1
4  15 0 1 0 0

pivot_wider(df1, id_cols = age, names_from = category,
              values_from = category, values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)
# A tibble: 4 × 5
    age     A     B     C     D
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1    12     2     0     0     0
2    15     0     1     0     0
3    13     0     0     1     0
4    14     0     1     0     1
```

Comment: I tried using the `table(agdf)` method. I want the output to be in a data frame structure but when I try to do `as.data.frame.matrix(table(agdf))`, it gives the error of `Error in `[.default`(x, , i) : incorrect number of dimensions`. Also if the original df has other columns (I omitted them for simplicity), how can I keep these values intact when I use `aggregate()`? It seems using `FUN=length` turns all those columns into the same count value, but I only want one such count value. How can I do that?

Comment: @AlgoManiac in your example, your data has two columns. You need to subset your data to only have two columns and then run any of the four codes provided. If you need a dataframe, use any of the last two methods if you are unable to transform a table to a dataframe. Also  I dont know why you are sticking to aggregate yet `aggregate` is not for reshaping data but just to `aggregate`. If you need to use `aggregate` then use `reshape` afterwards

Comment: I have tried using `table()` on an aggregated df, but it seems to not give the correct output. The counts of each category A, B, C and D are only 0 and 1. Does not seem to have other values. Whereas the aggregated df contains the correct frequency.

Comment: @AlgoManiac the df1 is the table before aggregation. If you read my comment i clearly stated that you do not need aggregate. You use aggregate+reshape

Comment: If using the `table()` method, do you know how one can turn the table(df) into a dataframe while keeping "age" as a column? Normally when turning into dataframe, the age variable becomes the row index, but I want it to be a column

Comment: @AlgoManiac use `tibble::rownames_to_column` function, or simply save the dataframe and use `cbind(row.names(your_new_dataframe), your_new_dataframe)`